# How do you print a hash in Django 1.7 and store it in a database?

Tags: python, django

I created a hash that I am going to use later for confirmation email logic like this:

```
import hashlib, datetime, random 

def hash(request):
    username = 'johndoe' #inserted line to simplify the code
    random_str = str(random.random()).encode('utf-8')
    salt = hashlib.sha1(random_str).hexdigest()[:5]
    salted = (salt + username).encode('utf-8')
    activation_key = hashlib.sha1(salted).hexdigest()
    return render_to_response('ftest/display.html', activation_key)
```

My first question is how do I print this in the html so that I can see it when the html renders?

This doesn't seem to work in my display.html :

```
<p> This is the activation key {{activation_key}} </p>
```

Next, how would I define this hash field in the database? Would it just be a charfield like:

```
hash = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: I don't think displaying hash value on template is good as your going to use it for email confirmation. I think yous should use session for this case. And i think CharField would be fine to store hashvalues as Models feild.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm not going to display hash values. I was just curious why the hash values weren't being printed out. Printing out the hash value is for my own testing purposes.

Comment: Also have a look at [django-uuidfield](https://github.com/dcramer/django-uuidfield) for these purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

render_to_response expects a dict :

```
return render_to_response('ftest/display.html', {'activation_key': activation_key})
```

A CharField is the right way to go.

Comment: Wow, I need to get some sleep, I'm making too many easy mistakes. Thanks for the clarification!